# Edit account menu item in user menu

Tags: hooks, navigation

I want to add edit account menu item in user menu, I want the URL to be user/{user_id}/edit.
How can I achieve this without menu_token module.
I also tried creating menu item programatically as follow

```
$items = array();
  global $user;
  $user_id = $user->uid;
  $items['user/' . $user_id . '/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit account',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
```

But newly created menu item only shows at back-end i.e. at structure/menu/user-menu but it doesn't display it on front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hook_menu() {
  $items = array();
  global $user;
  $user_id = $user->uid;
  $items['user/' . $user_id . '/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit account',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_user_edit',
    'access callback' => 'MYMODULE_user_edit_access',
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
    'file path' => 'modules/user'
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_user_edit() {
  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);
  return drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $account);
}

function MYMODULE_user_edit_access(){
  global $user;
  return user_edit_access($user);
}
```

Try above code. :)